# Recommended dynamic runtime configuration technique on nuxtjs (other than dotenv)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, runtime-configuration

I have been trying to use [publicRuntimeConfig / privateRuntimeConfig](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config#migrating-to-the-nuxtjs-runtime-config-from-the-env-property)
On nuxt 2.4.1, I have defined my runtime config as follows on *nuxt.config.js*

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    DATA_API_HOST_URL: process.env.VUE_APP_DATA_API_HOST_URL,
  },
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    AUTH_APP_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
```

and calling it as follows on my *login.vue*

```
asyncData( ctx ) {
  console.log(ctx.$config.DATA_API_HOST_URL)
  //some activity
}
```

1. The keys are showing up on *$config* inside *asyncData*. I debugged on chrome dev tools. But value is not read from *process.env.VUE_APP_DATA_API_HOST_URL*. The value is showing up as *undefined*. However, *process.env.VUE_APP_DATA_API_HOST_URL* is showing the value OK. The whole point is to move away from *process.env*.
2. *this.$config.DATA_API_HOST_URL* also does not access the values.
3. *'${DATA_API_HOST_URL}'* is shown in examples but I believe it is only for explicit param declarations at *asyncData* like `asyncData( { $config : {DATA_API_HOST_URL})`.
4. When I pass values as it is using `DATA_API_HOST_URL: process.env.VUE_APP_DATA_API_HOST_URL || 'https://test.api.com'`, it seems to copy the value fine using *ctx.$config.DATA_API_HOST_URL*!

Looking to me like copying *process.env* to **RuntimeConfig* has a problem!

What is the recommended way of importing and using runtime configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation in the Nuxt blog post you marked, the feature your are trying to use is released in 2.13 (you´re using 2.4 if i not misunderstood). That could be the reason behind the behaviour you're seeing.
I'd recommend update your project dependencies or trying another approach.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use Docker to set dynamic runtime config like link below:

https://dev.to/frontendfoxes/dockerise-your-nuxt-ssr-app-like-a-boss-a-true-vue-vixens-story-4mm6

Comment: Even for dockerizing, I would need to be able to read the configuration from within the app / context. And we may not want to hard-code like I'm doing in the work around (step 4).

Comment: I seem don't see any dynamic runtime configure as in the provided post link, it's just a generalize dockerize the nuxtjs to a container, I don't see any passing link parameter or environment variable from docker-compose to nuxtjs, can you clarify the point as per the question?